# Проблема после подключения библиотеки супорта

Tags: android, android-support-library

Подключил в гредле библиотеку:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
}
```

Ребилд прошел без ошибок и приложение запустилось!

Но на нем есть одна кнопка и пункты меню! Проблема в том, что кнопка не отображается на экране!!

Хотелось бы знать почему!

Код активности:

```
public class My extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Ее леяута:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Так должен выглядеть результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в результате меню есть, а кнопки на экране нету!!!

Как можно это исправить ?

Comment: Возможно, кнопка уехала под тулбар. Попробуйте добавить ещё кнопок в разметку. Если они будут видны, значит так и есть.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, добавил еще, но их все равно нет(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы переопределили не тот метод `onCreate`, необходимо переопределить метод

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

а у вас переопределен метод

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
```

Comment: спасибо !! моя невнимательность (